# Why are anchor tags not working in jsbin or jsfiddle ?

Tags: html, jsfiddle, jsbin

JSBIN:    http://jsbin.com/mucume/edit?html,output

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ksvq4buc/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
  <br/>
      <a href="http://www.yahoo.com"> Yahoo </a>
</body>
</html>
```

In both the examples above, clicking on the links does not do anything. Why are anchor hyperlinks disabled on these sites

Comment: JSBIN: `Refused to display 'https://www.google.no/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=wbsyVuWVKaur8wfdlq2wDg&gws_rd=ssl' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.` and JSFIDDLE: `Refused to display 'https://www.yahoo.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.` ..perhaps that will help you? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open the browser's console to see the reason. Both sites show:

> Refused to display 'https://www.yahoo.com/' in a frame because it set
>   'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

For more information on that, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options